# Unexpected token: 'less than' symbol in SQL query

Tags: sql, excel, vba, db2, adodb

I'm trying to use ADODB in an Excel macro to pull in data from a DB2 table with a SQL query. I'm running into an error caused by an expression in the query. The relevant code is below- **the issue is coming from the IIF statement in the first line**. (Other SQL queries within the project I'm working on have pulled in without any issues.)

```
SQL_input = SQL_input & "SELECT DB2.TABLE1.CAT, DB2.TABLE1.BRD, DB2.TABLE1.ITEM, Sum(IIF(ITEM_ORD_Q-ITEM_RECV_Q < 0,0,ITEM_ORD_Q-ITEM_RECV_Q)) AS OO" & vbCrLf
SQL_input = SQL_input & "FROM DB2.TABLE2 INNER JOIN DB2.TABLE ON (DB2.TABLE2.ITEM = DB2.TABLE1.ITEM) AND (DB2.TABLE2.BRD = DB2.TABLE1.BRD) AND (DB2.TABLE2.CAT = DB2.TABLE1.CAT)" & vbCrLf
SQL_input = SQL_input & "WHERE (((DB2.TABLE2.ITEM_GRP_CAT)=" & cat & ") AND ((DB2.TABLE2.ITEM_GRP_code_C)='" & code & "'))" & vbCrLf
SQL_input = SQL_input & "GROUP BY DB2.TABLE1.CAT, DB2.TABLE1.BRD, DB2.TABLE1.ITEM;"

AdoRS1.Open (SQL_input)
```

The error I'm getting says: *SQL0104N An unexpected token "<" was found following ""*

Does anyone know how I could change the string for the query to make it work?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK - DB2 does not support `IIF` which is an MS Access and SQL Server (2012+) method. Consider the ANSI SQL counterpart of `CASE`, available in nearly all SQL dialects:

```
SUM(CASE 
        WHEN ITEM_ORD_Q-ITEM_RECV_Q < 0
        THEN 0
        ELSE ITEM_ORD_Q-ITEM_RECV_Q
    END) AS OO
```